# Send bearer token in Swagger using Swagger-Net

Tags: swagger, swashbuckle

I have recently made the transition from Swashbuckle to [Swagger-Net](https://github.com/heldersepu/Swagger-Net).  One problem that I'm having after making the change is that now I'm unable to call my APIs which require a token sent in the Authorization header.  Below are how I had the code in SwaggerConfig.cs before in Swashbuckle and now Swagger-Net

**Swashbuckle**

```
//section for .EnableSwagger
c.ApiKey("apiKey")
.Description("API Key Authentication")
.Name("Authorization")
.In("header");

//section for .EnableSwaggerUI
c.EnableApiKeySupport("Authorization", "header");
```

**Swagger-Net**

```
//section for .EnableSwagger
c.ApiKey("Authorization", "header", "API Key Authentication");
```

For Swagger-Net I can't find any equivalent of the .EnableAPIKeySupport in the .EnableSwaggerUI portion.  After accessing the /Swagger UI rendering and using Authorize passing my token it is not sending that token to the API.  I can tell it's not being sent as it is not in the sample CURL given.

Comment: Do you see the lock icons on the actions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes on [Swagger-Net](https://github.com/heldersepu/Swagger-Net) the `ApiKey` is all you need

```
c.ApiKey("apiKey", "header", "API Key Authentication", typeof(KeyAuthAttribute));
```

Here is a working example:
http://turoapi.azurewebsites.net/swagger/ui/index#/Echo/Echo_Post

The "protected" actions  will show a lock icon on the right
[image]

And when you execute them you can see that the curl has the right stuff
[image]

And the code behind is here:
https://github.com/heldersepu/TuroApi/blob/master/TuroApi/App_Start/SwaggerConfig.cs#L67

Comment: I looked in a bit more depth and believe I found the problem.  With the sample site that you gave if I use POST then it is sending the apiKey.  If you try the Get or Put then it is not sending the key.  Is this by design and is there a way to send for all request types?  We are using the key for all request types as a security mechanism.

Comment: Yes that is by design, only the Post has the `KeyAuthAttribute`, here is the code: https://github.com/heldersepu/TuroApi/blob/master/TuroApi/Controllers/EchoController.cs

Comment: Look at the lock icons in the swagger ui, those action are the ones protected

Comment: If you want to force the  security on all actions you can do that with an iDocumentFilter, you will be injecting (`"security":[{"apiKey":[]}]}}`)  to the swagger.json

Comment: Thanks for the details, I didn't realize that certain end-points had the lock icon, I'll look into a custom iDocumentFilter.  The feature to send apiKey to any request type already existed in swashbuckle so thought it would be here as well but understand they are different frameworks.

Comment: Hit me up if you get stuck with the iDocumentFilter, maybe what you need could be incorporated into Swagger-Net.

Comment: @HelderSepulveda Hi! Have same problem, but in my WebAPI project I don't see lock icon on any of the methods. I do get Authorize button and when pass token in - it doesn't pass anything on test requests. We use custom attribute + ActionFilter to process authorizations and all of our methods require same token passed in a headers

Comment: @katit post a new question with a sample of your code

Comment: Done. Created swagger-net tag as well: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57062684/swagger-net-supporting-api-key-authentication