# Swagger-Net supporting API Key authentication

Tags: asp.net-web-api, swagger, swagger-net

We are using token authentication in our WebAPI application. Every call (other then method which obtains key) uses same pattern.

`Authorization: our-token v01544b7dce-95c1-4406-ad4d-b29202d0776c`

We implemented authentication using `Attribute` and `IActionFilter`

Controllers look like so:

```
[RoutePrefix("api/tms/auth")]
    public class AuthController : BaseController
    {
        public ISecurityService SecurityService { get; set; }

        [TokenAuth]
        [Route("logout")]
        [HttpPost]
        public HttpResponseMessage Logout()
        {
            try
            {
                this.SecurityService.InvalidateAccessToken(this.StaticContextWrapperService.AccountId, token, HttpContext.Current.Request.UserHostAddress);

                // Return OK status
                return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
            }
            catch (LoginException le)
            {
                return this.LogoutFailureResponse(le.Message);
            }
        }


        private HttpResponseMessage LogoutFailureResponse(string message)
        {
            return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest)
            {
                Content = new StringContent(message, Encoding.UTF8, "text/plain")
            };
        }
    }
```

Swagger config has following:

```
c.ApiKey("our-token", "header", "Our Token Authentication");
```

Swagger UI showing "Authorize" button and I can paste token into field on popup.
However, no headers passed in any tests. And no methods have "lock" icon on them.

EDIT:

I also tried:

```
c.ApiKey("our-token", "header", "Our Token Authentication", typeof(TokenAuthAttribute));
```

Where attribute is just attribute:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method | AttributeTargets.Class)]
    public class TokenAuthAttribute : Attribute
    {
    }
```

Then we use IActionFilter to check if attribute applied to method and thats where we check for permission. This is done to use service via DI.

EDIT2:

I made change to how Attribute declared:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method | AttributeTargets.Class)]
        public class TokenAuthAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
        {
        }
```

After than Swagger UI started to show all methods as secured, so it does analyze that it's in fact `AuthorizeAttribute`, not just Attribute

After that it started to put header like so:
`our-token: ZGV2OnYwMTA2YjZmYjdhLWRlNTUtNDZlNC1hN2Q4LTYxMjgwNTg2M2FiZQ==`

Where it should be:
`Authorization: our-token GV2OnYwMTA2YjZmYjdhLWRlNTUtNDZlNC1hN2Q4LTYxMjgwNTg2M2FiZQ==`

Answer (score 1):

If I'm not mistaken you should have:

```
c.ApiKey("our-token", "header", "Our Token Authentication", typeof(TokenAuthAttribute));
```

With that in place, all the actions tagged with `TokenAuth` should show a lock icon

---

You can see it in action in one of mine:
https://turoapi.azurewebsites.net/swagger/ui/index

And the code behind that is here:
https://github.com/heldersepu/TuroApi/blob/master/TuroApi/App_Start/SwaggerConfig.cs#L67

---

[image: swagger-net_auth]

Comment: I just put EDIT on my original post. I don't think it will work like that, our Attribute is not `AuthorizeAttribute`. I was thinking that adding line in swagger-net config will just add needed headers to all calls without trying to get in and analyze what methods and code we use for authorization

Comment: If it is not working with `typeof(TokenAuthAttribute)` this might be a bug...
can you create a small project reproducing this on GitHub?

Comment: See if this is related to the extra tags on the action... to test create a vanilla controller with no RoutePrefix and the action with only `TokenAuth` see if that makes a difference

Comment: Added EDIT2 to explain

Comment: Interesting... smells like a bug

Comment: ApiKey - https://github.com/heldersepu/Swagger-Net/blob/d70d1dd54205e80962e2c5d17192c592c7dc81d7/Swagger.Net/Application/SwaggerDocsConfig.cs#L107

Comment: Something must be going wrong here: https://github.com/heldersepu/Swagger-Net/blob/d70d1dd54205e80962e2c5d17192c592c7dc81d7/Swagger.Net/Application/SwaggerDocsConfig.cs#L329

Comment: Looks like a problem here? `if (type == null) type = typeof(AuthorizeAttribute);`

Comment: @katit on your case, you do have to pass a type because yours is custom, and that condition will be skipped... I have to spend some time on this to reproduce in the unit tests

Comment: I do pass type, but again, it only starts to work when my TokenAuthAttribute inherits from AuthorizationAttribute. If it's simply inherits from Attribute (what we need) - it doesn't work.

Comment: I think I got a fix, does this test look like your code?:
https://github.com/heldersepu/Swagger-Net/blob/master/Tests/Swagger.Net.Dummy.Core/Controllers/ProtectedResources2Controller.cs

Comment: Try with latest when you can:
https://www.nuget.org/packages/Swagger-Net/8.3.23.102

Comment: Nope. But closer. My attribute allows class or method use. I cover whole controllers with this attribute so, it's class use. I have one controller where I use this attribute on method and it's marked with "lock". `[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method | AttributeTargets.Class)]`

Comment: Ouch... for the class we are screwed, right now I do not see a way forward to propagate that to the actions ... but if you do see a way send a PR

Comment: Maybe this will help? This was my question on how to determine if whole controller covered with attribute: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53510398/webapi-iactionfilter-implementation-how-do-i-read-custom-controller-attribute

Comment: `actionDescriptor.ControllerDescriptor` interesting I will test incorporating that here:
https://github.com/heldersepu/Swagger-Net/commit/91141eff749216c213e30a3537456c19f1394f6e

Comment: Yep. If not on action - check controller and it should do it.

Comment: Sorry for the LOOONG wait been busy with other projects, try with latest:
https://www.nuget.org/packages/Swagger-Net/8.3.23.104